# mysql join get info from 2 rows

Tags: mysql, join

i have 2 tables:

```
players
id  |  dni | name
-----------------  
1      222    mike
2      333    gerard
3      444    mark
4      555    alfred
5      666    thomas
5      777    nicolas

teams
id  |  dni1 | dni2 | cat 
------------------------  
1      222    333    1
2      444    555    1
3      666    333    2
4      777    222    2
```

what i want is to make a select statement depending on the cat. so for

cat=1 should be:

mike gerard 
mark alfred

and for cat=2 should be:

thomas gerard 
nicolas mike

i tryed many join statements but i cant figure it out, can you help me please?

**EDIT to make it more difficult, the players table have a new colum= points**

```
players
    id  |  dni | name | points
    --------------------------  
    1      222    mike     1
    2      333    gerard   2
    3      444    mark     3
    4      555    alfred   4
    5      666    thomas   5
    5      777    nicolas  6
```

now the result give us the sum of the points colums from both players and order by biggest sum number.
cat=1 should be:

mark alfred 7 
mike gerard 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t.cat, p1.name name1, p2.name name2, p1.points + p2.points points
from teams AS t
join players AS p1 ON p1.dni = t.dni1
join players AS p2 on p2.dni = t.dni2
where cat = 1
order by points desc
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9a80/2)